# Symmetric Borel sets in the plane

Tags: measure-theory

How will I show that the sigma algebra consisting of all Borel sets in the plane, which are symmetric about the line $y=x$, is generated by sets of the form $(a,b) \times (a,b)$? I could show upto the fact that any set in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets of the form $(a,b) \times (a,b)$ is a Borel set, symmetric about $y=x$. But I am totally confused about the part that any symmetric Borel set is generated in such a way. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = \{(x, y): y > x\}$. Note that it is enough to show that sigma algebra $S$ generated by sets of the form $(a, b) \times (a, b) \cap P$ contains all open subsets of $P$. This follows from: For every point $p \in P$ and $r > 0$, there is an open set in $S$ of diameter less than $r$ that contains $p$. You can see this by drawing a picture.